# Disable Android hardware acceleration for the splash screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, hardware-acceleration

Adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the application element significantly improves its user experience - the app is using long lists and the scrolling in those lists is much smoother when we enable the hardware acceleration. However, our splash screen image is being "broken" when we enable it - we see gray lines on top of it. Once we disable the hardware acceleration the splash screen looks good.

Is there a way to disable the hardware acceleration only for the splash screen? How can we do this in our Java class?

Comment: Any idea why only your splash screen looks poor with hardware acceleration?

Comment: Most probably because the splash screen is 9-patch png image. All the other screens are not a static image.

Answer (score 0):

> If you need more fine-grained control, you can enable hardware
>   acceleration for a given window at runtime:

```
    getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

Comment: But how can I get the window of the splash screen?

Comment: Isn't your splash screen just another activity?

Comment: I'm using Apache Cordova (Phonegap). My Java file do not refer to the splash screen as this is defined via the project config.xml file. So the question is how can I get the splash screen so that I can use the getWindow as you wrote above.

Comment: Probably not possible with Cordova since that abstracts that layer away